# Cronatab missing on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, cron

crontab is missing from my CentOS installation.
Yum says it's installed and up to date.

/etc/crontab is present, but no crontab program is on the disk.

Anyone had this problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the package `cronie` installed? At least on Fedora that is where my `/usr/bin/crontab` is from,

Comment: Other package names to try: `cron`, `vixie-cron`

Comment: vixie-cron - that's got it.
Many thanks.